# password hashing in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to StackOverflow, and to the development world. Currently learning JS and node, I am developing a personal project which will be a task management web app. I wrote the register/auth controllers for user data inserts/checks in DB (using MySQL), but ATM I am saving the password in plain text. I want to hash the password and save it in the DB, but when I go look into the table, the passed value is saved as "Object Promise", so it's not currently hashing I think. How can I correctly save the value in registration and validate it in auth? Below is the code of both auth and register controllers. Thanks.

register-controller:

```
var mysqlConnection = require ('../config');
const bcrypt = require ('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
module.exports.register=function(req,res){
  var today = new Date();
  var users={
      "firstname":req.body.firstname,
      "lastname" : req.body.lastname,
      "email":req.body.email,
      "password":bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds),
      "signup_date":today,
      "last_login_date":today
  }

  mysqlConnection.query('SELECT count(email) as count FROM users where email = "' + req.body.email + '"', function (error, results) {
    console.log(error, results[0].email);
  }) 
  mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?',users, function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(error, results);
    if (error) {
      res.json(
          error
      )
    }else{
        console.log('User registered succesfully.');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
}
```

and this is auth-controller:

```
var mysqlConnection = require ('../config');
const bcrypt = require ('bcrypt');

module.exports.auth = function (req, res, next) {
  var email = req.body.email 
  var password = req.body.password
  console.log(email, password);
  mysqlConnection.query('SELECT password FROM users where email = "' + email + '"', function (error, results) {
    console.log(error, results[0]);
    if (error) {
        res.error = error;
    }else{
      if(results.length >0){
        bcrypt.compare(password,results[0].password, function (err,res){
          if(password === results[0].password){
              console.log('User logged in succesfully.');
              res.error = error;
              res.user = results[0];
              res.redirect('/');
          }else{
              res.error = error;
              res.user = null;
        }
      }
        )}
      else{
        res.error = error;
        res.user = null;
        res.redirect('/register');
      }
    }
    next();
  });
}
```

Comment: `bcrypt.hash` is *asynchronous*, just like `bcrypt.compare`. You need to resolve the promise or pass a callback so that you have the *result* of the operation when writing to the database.

Comment: yep, you're right, sorry.

Comment: k thanks, solved the Promise and also I have put all the other queries in the callback hell xD now all's left is the auth part for pw comparison. Sorry but I am completely new to development world, started about 1 month ago, I think that am already at a good point in so little time.